# Plotting Bloch sphere in QuTiP

Tags: programming, simulation, bloch-sphere, qutip, open-quantum-systems

Is there anyone who reproduced the Bloch sphere given in the paper **QuTiP: An open-source Python framework for the dynamics of open quantum systems** by *J. R. Johansson, P. D. Nation, Franco Nori*? I am trying to reproduce the Figure 10: *Bloch sphere representation of the Landau-Zener transition*. The code they used is given in the appendix of the paper.

But when I am trying to plot this, I am getting an error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'indices'`

Can anyone please help me to correct this one to get the exact Bloch sphere plot?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very old paper, corresponding to version one of the software.  It is now on version 4.x.  It is best to see the current documentation for how to use the Bloch sphere: http://qutip.org/docs/latest/guide/guide-bloch.html

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Can you please help me to find an answer to this question: